C++: C union struct has to be initialized with double "{"
Why does my C struct my_type_t has to be initialized using double { in C++ but one { in C is enough?
#include <iostream>
#include "types.h"

int main()
{
    my_type_t t = { { .bla = 23, .sab = 0 } };
    std::cout << "BLA: " << t.bla << "\n";

    return 0;
}

"types.h":
#ifndef _TYPES_H_
#define _TYPES_H_

#include "stdint.h"

extern "C" {

typedef union my_type
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t bla : 8;
        uint32_t sab : 8;
    };
    struct
    {
        uint32_t sabbla: 16;
    };
    uint16_t raw;
} my_type_t;

}
#endif

Otherwise I receive the message
main.cpp:6:41: error: too many initializers for ‘my_type_t’ {aka ‘my_type’}
    6 |     my_type_t t = { .bla = 23, .sab = 0 };
      |                                         ^


"Why does my C struct my_type_t has to be initialized using double { in C++ but one { in C is enough?" - because C and C++ are completely different languages with different rules (yes, they share a common heritage, but they have diverged wildly and are by now mostly entirely distinct languages that just share some interoperability).

Note that C++ does not have C structs.  It has C++ structs.

identifiers starting with _ and upper case letter are reserved in C and  C++. Do not use _TYPES_H_. Do TYPES_H_ for example, but no leading _.

@JesperJuhl Not very helpful. Presumably the C++ designers made this divergence from C for a reason. Probably to resolve some ambiguity introduced by other C++ features.

C doesn't care.  C++ try's.  There is more to my_type_t than you are giving it.

Your question is about C++, why do you tag it C?

@Barmar That's your opinion and you are welcome to have it. We all attempt to help in each our own way. If you have something more helpful and/or specific to add, then please do.

Neither designated initializers nor anonymous structs are standard C++, at least as of C++17.

@dbush The designated initializers are part of C++20: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization

Can't repro: https://godbolt.org/z/oEYMaco4o (only with higher warning level on msvc). Some details about compiler and compiler flags are needed.

@3CxEZiVlQ They're asking about a difference between C and C++.

@JesperJuhl I doubt the C++ committee makes changes capriciously, just because they don't want to be like C. Yes, that's my opinion, but it's informed by having been a member of a standardization committee in the past. Language changes always have to be justified.

WG14 (C standards committee) does not feel any onus upon them to be compatible with C++.  WG21 (C++ standards committee) takes C compatibility into account, but not all C features or C syntax fits in with C++.  (In my opinion, WG21 is hurting the C++ language and community by being even semi-compatible ... in contrast to Sutter's Syntax 2 or Baxter's New Circle experiments.  Just my 2¢.  I'm not on the committee; but some of my colleagues are.)

@Eljay Is this something that existed in C when C++ was designed, or is it something that was added later to each language, and they did it differently?

@Barmar, curly-bracketed initialization of structure and array objects has been in C since before the first edition of K&R (1978).  That was extended with designated initializers, such as appear in the example code, in C99, so after C++ started diverging.  It's interesting that this was not reconciled in C++11, which incorporated the C++ side of a push to harmonize the two, and more interesting that not having managed that in C++11, the committee decided it could do in C++20.

it should be noted that C++ designated initializers are almost a subset of the C ones.  They are more restricted then their C counterpart.

Or if you consider the discrepant feature to be anonymous structures (with initialization thereof) then that did not enter C until C11, after C++ was well established as a separate language, and C++ does not have it to this day.

The definition of my_type is not standard C++ at all.
In C++ a union can be an anonymous member of a class, but a class (i.e. struct) cannot.
So the definition would have to be
extern "C" {

typedef union my_type
{
    struct
    {
        uint32_t bla : 8;
        uint32_t sab : 8;
    } a;
    struct
    {
        uint32_t sabbla: 16;
    } b;
    uint16_t raw;
} my_type_t;

and then the only designated initializers that would make sense are
my_type_t t = { .a = { .bla = 23, .sab = 0 } };

or
my_type_t t = { { .bla = 23, .sab = 0 } };

where the inner set of braces is the initializer for the first element of t, i.e. t.a as in normal aggregate initialization without designated initializers.
But
my_type_t t = { .bla = 23, .sab = 0 };

is then not allowed, which makes sense because bla and sab are not direct members of t and can't be looked up in the scope of t either. A special lookup behavior would be surprising, in my opinion.
Anonymous struct members where added to C with C11 and were never incorporated into C++. While C++98 was mostly a superset of C89 (although exceptions are listed in [diff.iso]), there are many constructs that were added to later revisions of C that were never added to later revisions of C++. The languages diverged, although there is also some standardization effort to keep a large common subset compatible between the two languages. My guess is that simply nobody yet bothered to spent the effort to push a proposal to add anonymous structs through the standardization process.
Everything else is a compiler-specific extension of the standard language and it would be up to the compiler to decide what initialization syntax is supported. If your compiler fails to compile the code, then it is a limitation of that specific compiler's implementation choice for its specific anonymous struct language extension.
However, as already posted in a comment linking to https://godbolt.org/z/oEYMaco4o, recent versions of major compilers all seem to support both the anonymous struct as well as the initialization syntax with a single pair of braces in C++20 mode as long as they are not asked to operate in a pedantic or strictly standard conforming mode.

So, with respect to the OP's "Why does my C struct my_type_t has to be initialized using double { in C++", one could summarize as: any such limitation is a matter of the implementation of a language extension (anonymous structures) by some particular C++ compiler.

This is the kind of answer the OP was clearly looking for, it shows how this feature evolved after the languages diverged, which explains why they're different.
